# How to access the mobile number of a device on which J2ME application is running?

Tags: java

I am developing an Messaging application using J2ME for which i need to access the mobile number of a device on which application is running.
I tried to find out the api's related to it but was unable to find it.
So Plz can any one tell me is there any other method to find the mobile number in J2ME?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it is possible--create a SIM applet that will extract the MSISDN from one of the Elementary Files (EF) of the SIM (I am not sure which one). Then, with SATSA, make the JME application communicate with the SIM applet.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, that's impossible, not all J2ME devices are mobile phones and even if the device running J2ME is a mobile phone its not always aware of its phone number. There are some tips and tricks to accomplish this task eg. from a way for some Nokia devices ([look here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?71718-Phone-Number&highlight=phone%20number)) by reading some system properties ('com.nokia.mid.msisdn') to some 'silly' ways of sending an sms to a specially prepared sms receiver/sender who just replies another sms, then your application can listen to incoming sms with a specific data and read its mobile number.